# Nao consigo chamar uma imagem de fundo no tkinter numa segunda janela como faço?

Tags: python, imagem, tkinter

Código

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

def createNewWindow():
    newWindow = tk.Toplevel(app)
    img2 = PhotoImage(file="Entrada.gif")
    Label(newWindow,image=img2).pack()

app = tk.Tk()
app.title("Imagem Fundo")
buttonExample = tk.Button(app, 
              text="Create new window",
              command=createNewWindow)
buttonExample.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use o `place` para esta finalidade, segue um exemplo:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()


def createNewWindow():
    newWindow = tk.Toplevel(app)
    img2 = PhotoImage(file="load-loading.gif")
    Label(newWindow, image=img2).pack().place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)


app.title("Imagem Fundo")
buttonExample = tk.Button(app, text="Create new window", command=createNewWindow)
buttonExample.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Saída:

[image: tela com imagem de fundo]

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10181434/5429980)